# Why my bi-weekly salary after taxes doesn't sum up my yearly income

Tags: salary, payroll-taxes

I'm a little bit confused about my paycheck. We have an internal tool that helps me calculate my bi-weekly paycheck, the details are as follows... keep in mind that my F1 OPT status exempts me from Social Security + Medicare.

Annual Salary
$100000

Bi-weekly Gross Pay
$3,846.15

Federal Withholding
$741.26

Social Security
$0.00

Medicare
$0.00

California
$270.79

CA SDI
$34.62

Net Pay
$2,799.48

Now, my salary is supposed to be 100k per year. Now, let's ignore taxes for a minute, I just want to figure out the logic behind this simple calculation. If I add my Bi-weekly gross pay ($3,846.15 * 2) this means I earn $7692.3 per month, or in other words $92307.6 per year ($7692.3*12). Where did those extra $8k disappear?... What I mean is that by doing this I was expecting to get around 99k. I'm new at calculating taxes, so what is the explanation?

Comment: Your calculation only uses 24 pay periods in the year. There are 26 fortnights in the year not 24.

Comment: 52 weeks/ year, 52/2 = 26.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**In some months there are three biweekly payments.**

If you multiply $3846.15 by 26 (the number of biweekly periods in the year) you get $99999.90. I wouldn't worry about the extra ten cents.

Comment: You are actually getting a slight bonus, because approximately once every 11 years there are 27 biweekly paydays in a year. That's a 0.3% bonus.

Comment: Unless your payroll department is totally incompetent  (some are), the last bi-weekly paycheque in your salary year will be for an amount to bring your total paid to the exact annual salary total,,,

Comment: Doesn't biweekly mean twice per week. The correct term for being paid every two weeks is fortnight.

Comment: Biweekly can mean either twice a week or every two weeks depending on context and location... Love this language...

Comment: @DJohnM -  that is why we use fortnightly. If you write the sentence: "I get a cheque biweekly" what does it mean? Does it mean I get a cheque twice a week or does it mean I get a cheque every two weeks? Or both?? And why do you spell cheque as check. Imagine if I wrote: "I would like to check your check" Why not spell it like most other English speaking nations - cheque !!!

Comment: If you're North American you're as likely to get "what do you mean by fortnight?"

Comment: It's two sennights, naturally...

Answer (score 6):

There are 26 pay periods for you bi-weekies. 3846.15 * 26 = 99999.90.

Comment: The average year has 365.2422 days. 365.2422 / 14 = 26.0887285714. So you get 26 paychecks in a year, but one year out of 12 you get 27 paychecks. So that makes up for the missing 10¢

Comment: I just checked and January 1st of this year was a Friday. If you got paid on January 1st then you will get a paycheck on December 31st making 2016 the year you get 27 paychecks in the year instead of 26.